# htaccess to mask my url path with another one?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to use the url domain.com/login but in the background (hidden) it should be the domain.com/account/index.php

Is there any possible way of doing this?

My current htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your file to..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^login$ account/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The `^` is the start of the path and the `$` is the end of it. If you need/want it looser you can take off either of them.

For example

```
RewriteRule ^login
```

would work for `/login` and `/logins`

```
RewriteRule ^logins?$
```

would also work and

```
RewriteRule ^logins$
```

would only match `/logins`.